# What is the blue border in ImageView in android studio?

Tags: android, imageview

I started learning Android development and I'm using Relative Layout. I want to know what this blue border means as shown in the below Screenshot

[image]

Initially, I wanted to position this image to the top. I did it using:
android:scaleType="fitStart" but this blue border was still there but this time only below. I am totally new to android programming. Any help would be appreciated.

**Layout Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/company_image" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/Company" 
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml layout file

Comment: that is just a selection box that is shown only in the design view. It wont be shown in the deployed application.

Comment: Dear @N J, being a new StackOverflow user, I don't know how to attach a file. Code:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/company_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/Company"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>



</RelativeLayout>
`

Comment: Dear @Lal, I have this idea. But if I want to add another view (say TextView) below it. It is added below the blue border but not directly below the image. I want to understand the concept of it.

Comment: Are you sure that the original image does not have those blank spaces? Try with an other image and see if that blank space exists or not..

Comment: Your TextView will be always below the blue line because the blue line is the ImageView, you can change the scaleType and gravity of the image inside the ImageView to fit the bottom of ImageView and move it to the top for a better rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blue line is only a **virtual visualization of the view** selected in your layout. Here, your image have a scaleType who don't take the entire space of your view (ImageView). So there is a white space between the top of the ImageView (in blue) and the image (also between the image and the bottom of ImageView)

Comment: Is there a way I can remove this whitespace?

Comment: Of course, as said below, you can change the scaleType https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html and gravity. You will understand by changing these two parameters in your imageView, does not hesitate to test everything.